# DataTables - how to render data with custom tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

This is how I use my custom tag in JSP

```
<utility:displayStatus value="${consumerForm.status }" />
```

When it comes to DataTables, I try to render the column like this :

```
 "columnDefs": [ 
                {
                    "targets": [ 0, 1 ],
                    "render" : function ( data, type, row ) {
                        var renderer = '';
                        renderer += '<a href="view?msgId='+ row.msgId+'">' + data + '</a>';

                        return renderer;
                    }
                },
                {
                    "targets": 5,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "orderable": false,
                    "type" : "html",
                    "render" : function ( data, type, row ) {

                        var renderer = '<utility:displayStatus value="'+ data+'" />';
                        console.log(renderer)
                        return renderer;
                    }
                },
```

I can get the html link display correctly in the datatables, but

```
'<utility:displayStatus value="'+ data+'" />'
```

cannot be rendered.

I tried with other html tag like label, span and button....and the result is correct.

Is it anyway to let the datatables render the custom tag correctly? Or Datatables is not support for custom tag such as JSTL ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use a custom tag?

Comment: Because I'm getting an object list and convert to JSON, so some of the data are just indicator like "A", " I". I need to use a  custom tag to render the display. Moreover, I also need to render different display base on the user access, there is another custom tag to check the user access too.

Answer (score 0):

Browser want allowed you to display custom tags.
You can put your data in html tag's attribute like .

You can show/hide or customize your html tag in JS according to your data. Even you can access **data-DepartmentCode** further after rendering.

Cheers......